# Login/Registration System with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web

i'm trying to créât a member area to login in a web site but i have a difficulty in php code but the real problem is in my db so i don't know where is the problem

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in C:\wamp\www\EM\inscription.php on line 15
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0016  267504  {main}( )   ..\inscription.php:0
2   0.0081  275440  mysql_escape_string ( ) ..\inscription.php:15
Erreur SQL !
SELECT login(*) FROM membre WHERE login="Nassim Hasnaoui"
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM membre WHERE login="Nassim Hasnaoui"' at line 1
```

Comment: That's not valid SQL.

Comment: Why is the wildcard in brackets? What are you trying to select? It should be either `SELECT login FROM membre WHERE login="Nassim Hasnaoui"` or `SELECT * FROM membre WHERE login="Nassim Hasnaoui"`

Answer (score 0):

Change your current to code to the below and try.

From

```
SELECT login(*) FROM membre WHERE login="Nassim Hasnaoui"
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM membre WHERE login="Nassim Hasnaoui"
```

and

From

```
mysql_escape_string()
```

to

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```